# Repeat array date in php for fullcalendar

Tags: php

I have to be able to view on fullcalendar.io a series of shakes that are repeated.

With php I managed, to repeat an array, now I have difficulty display it on the calendar.

Here is the code

```
$aDate = '2016-09-20';
$rounds = array('Sera', 'Pomeriggio', 'Mattina', 'Notte', 'Riposo');

for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    $nextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($aDate)));
    echo "\n<br>" . $nextDate . " " . $rounds[$i%count($rounds)];
    $aDate = $nextDate;
}
```

Now for viewing on full calendar I have to create a similar array like this:

```
events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2010-01-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2010-01-05',
        }
    ]
```

I have tried in this world but it does not work. Give me a hand to solve.

```
$aDate = '2016-09-20';
$rounds = array('Sera', 'Pomeriggio', 'Mattina', 'Notte', 'Riposo');
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    $nextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($aDate)));

    $event_array[] = array(
            'id' => '1',
            'title' => $rounds[$i%count($rounds)],
            'start' => $nextDate,
            'color' => '#000'
        );

    $aDate = $nextDate;
}
```

thank you

Comment: Are you using any js plugin for calendar ? If yes , can you please share the name of the plugin?

Comment: @SachinVairagi I want to use the plugin and  [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io)   . I also wrote in my message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check below code [**NOTE:** I have managed to make a similar structure as you mentioned, you can changed according to satisfy full calendar needs]

```
<?php

$aDate = '2016-09-20';
$rounds = array('Sera', 'Pomeriggio', 'Mattina', 'Notte', 'Riposo');

$events = array();

for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    $nextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($aDate)));
    $event_array = array();
    $event_array['id'] = $i+1;
    $event_array['title'] = $rounds[$i%count($rounds)];
    $event_array['start'] = $nextDate;
    $event_array['color'] = '#000';

    $aDate = $nextDate;

    $events[] = $event_array;
}

$events = json_encode($events, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($events);
?>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: code updated.. check once again.. you need to adjust accordingly.. @Sixdas